# como añadir 2 shortcodes en un solo boton en wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, plugin

muy buenas amigos, quisiera saber si se puede agregar dos shortcodes en un boton en un boton, mi problema es que estoy medio novato y no se donde agregarlo ni como empezar ( apenas estoy "jugando" con el código de plugins y aprendiendo) sin embargo se que algunos plugins tienen shortcodes ya prediseñados lo cual esta bien pero no tienen la función que quiero y si la tienen, entonces esta incompleta la acción. verán los plugin que uso son la gran mayoría de esta pagina: https://simple-membership-plugin.com

estos shortcodes son los que casi se acercan a lo que quiero:

[swpm_update_level_to level="2" button_text="downgrade Level to basic"]

[swpm_update_level_to level="3" button_text="Update Level to member"]

[swpm_payment_button id=145 button_text="Suscribirse" new_window="1"]

[swpm_payment_button id=147 button_text="Suscribirse" new_window="1"]

la id 145 es para pagos en stripe y la id 147 es para pagos en PayPal pero la cuestión es esta,
lo que quiero que haga el botón es lo siguiente:

1.- que acepte el pago (ya sea PayPal o stripe)
2.- que suba o baje el nivel de membresía del miembro que hace el pago.

por si solos hacen las dos tareas, pero quiero juntarlos en un boton ¿hay alguna manera? o realmente no se puede, gracias de antemano.

colocar el shortcodes de estos modos no funciono

[swpm_payment_button id=145 button_text="Suscribirse" new_window="1"  pay_update level="3"]

[swpm_payment_button id=145 button_text="Suscribirse" new_window="1"  swpm_update_level_to level="3"]

[swpm_payment_button id=145 button_text="Suscribirse" new_window="1" (swpm_update_level_to level="3")]

Comment: En el shortcode puedes pasar varios parámetros, leer esos parámetros y decidir que hacer según lo que haya en dichos parámetros. Por ejemplo: `[pay_update id=145 level=1]` Ahí, según lo que haya en `id` haces el pago, y según lo que haya en `level` subes o bajas el nivel.

Comment: por ejemplo estoy en el nivel 1, acabo de entrar al login y quiero pagar una membresia, lo unico que debo de hacer es poner por ejemplo asi [swpm_payment_button id=147 button_text="Suscribirse" new_window="1" swpm_update_level_to level="2" ] asi?

Comment: Eso depende de la lógica que estés implementando. Ahí, podríamos decir que `swpm_update_level_to` está indicando que el usuario subirá al nivel 2. En el background habrá un código que recoja ese valor y actualice el nivel a `2`.

Comment: deja checo si funciona, si no entonces actualizo post

Comment: Si no funciona es porque la lógica en el backend (PHP)  no está acoplada a lo que mandas en el shortcode. No queda claro si es tu propio shortcode o usas un plugin ¿? Tú puedes escribir tus propios shortcode, mandarle los datos que requieras y hacer las acciones que requieras en la base de datos o donde sea. Sólo tienes que registrar el shortcode en `functions.php` y escribir también allí la función que recibe los datos de ese shortocde y a partir de ahí puedes incluir archivos/clases de PHP o lo que sea, prescindiendo así de plugin de terceros.

Comment: pues lo primero que era agregarle un pay_update dentro del shortcode no funciono y de ahi agregar dos shortcodes dentro de lo [ ] tampoco funciono

Comment: por cierto para tu pregunta de si uso plugin o no, como lo dije en el post uso el simple membership plugin aqui esta la documentadcion https://simple-membership-plugin.com/simple-membership-documentation/

Comment: Entiendo. Lo de `pay_update` era a manera de ejemplo, si creas tu propio shortcode, lo cual es posible e incluso recomendable, porque prescindirías de un plugin para hacer algo tan sencillo como eso, haciendo tu sitio más ligero y más seguro (los plugin son uno de los principales vectores de ataque en Wordpress). Pero si decides hacerlo con el plugin, tendrás que hacerlo a la manera del plugin, viendo en su documentación cuál es la forma definida por ellos para mandar esos parámetros juntos y si lo permiten. Si fuera tú, escribiría mi propio shortcode, prescindiendo del plugin.